# Regex to contain one optional word character somewhere

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to search a string in java and match for the following requirements:

- Begin with a non-word character or input begin - (\W|\A)
- Contain certain set of characters - [aceilnrv ]
- **Optionally contain one additional word character - \w?**
- Be in a certain length range - {13,15}
- End with a non-word chracter - \W

As an example:

I want "cervical cancer." and "cervical **x**ancer." to fit but "c**s**rvical **x**ancer." to not.

I've solved the first case with this regex:

```
String regex = "(\\W|\\A)([aceilnrv ]{13,15})\\W";
```

But the latter two cases are causing me headaches.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

**Detailed Example:**

- `Sentence with cervical cancer.` should pass because "cervical cancer" fits [aceilnrv ]{13,15}.
- `Sentence with cervical xancer.` should also pass because one typo in "cervical cancer" is OK.
- `Sentence with csrvical xancer.` "csrvical xancer" has two letters (s&x) that are not in [aceilnrv ] so it should fail.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want. Can you add some more examples of passing and failing strings and explain why they pass/fail?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a more detailed example.

Comment: If this is an option, you should be able to do it programmatically. My idea is to first check the string for characters that are NOT in your set. If you get 0 or 1 match, you can continue with other requirements.